# Reusing an evaluated expression without using a temp variable

Tags: javascript

As part of a larger JavaScript project that I'm working on, I have to process several fixed-width text files, extract a substring from each of line of the files, and add the text to an array, unless that text has already been extracted.  This presents a curious problem that I've not been able to find an answer for.

I need to extract the string with substring(), test if that extracted expression is part of the array, and then add the evaluated expression to the array.  There are two ways I can code this.  The first is to evaluate the substring twice, like this:

```
var nextLine = 'Really long string that I only need part of: ID123456';
var idArray = [];

if (idArray.indexOf (nextLine.substring (45)) === -1) {
    idArray.push (nextLine.substring (45));
}
```

The second is to use a temp variable to hold the result of the expression:

```
var nextLine = 'Really long string that I only need part of: ID123456';
var tempStr = nextLine.substring (45);
var idArray = [];

if (idArray.indexOf (tempStr) === -1) {
    idArray.push (tempStr);
}
```

The first snippet involves evaluating nextLine.substring (45) twice, while the second uses a temp variable that is only used twice.  Neither of these really appeal to me, but I don't know and haven't been able to find any other way around this.

Is there some trick for being able to test this expression and push it without evaluating it twice and without using a temp variable?

Comment: _"only used twice"_ - so more than once, in which case why doesn't using a variable for their purpose (holding a bit of information you need to use again) appeal?

Comment: In the interest of best practises and clean coding I'd like to know if there's a way to avoid leaving unused variables lying around.  This particular piece of code will potentially be run thousands of times a day, so I don't think I'm entirely unjustified find the best way to code it.  Besides, if there is a better way, I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: The `)` on the right side of `-1` should be on the left of `===`. For the top code.

Comment: If this is being run thousands of times a day, and you're worried about memory costs, you shouldn't be using `array.push()`.

Comment: Don't worry about _"leaving unused variables lying around"_ - write code that is easy for you to understand first and foremost.  Modern JS engines heavily optimise your code and take care about those things for you.  Just don't make it a global variable.

Comment: @JamesThorpe You should post that as the answer.

Comment: @Tom Burris - Fixed, but this isn't the actual code from the project, just pseudo-code I put together to demonstrate a point.  What's wrong with array.push()?  I need to do further processing on the strings once I've read in the whole file and stripped out the duplicates, so putting the strings into an array seemed like the best option.  The individual arrays aren't that large as it's only one per log file, but there's an awful lot of files.  What would you suggest for this?

Comment: A modern computer executes several million instructions *per second*. If a temporary variable is created thousands of times per day, it's just a drop in the ocean.

Comment: @xarxziux https://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/lets-get-those-javascript-arrays-to-work-fast/

Comment: @TomBurris Bear in mind that a lot of what that talks about is implementation detail which is hidden away - parts of this could easily be optimised by the engine and change between versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a variable really bothers you, kindly rearrange and put it inside a scope.

```
var nextLine = 'Really long string that I only need part of: ID123456';
var idArray = []; {
    var tempStr = nextLine.substring(45);
    if (idArray.indexOf(tempStr) === -1) {
        idArray.push(tempStr);
    }
}
```

Honestly, don't waste your time on small stuff.

Comment: OK, thanks for taking the time to reply.  The project I'm undertaking is a big leap for me so I wanted to be sure I was doing it right.  It just looked like there should be a better way of coding this particular snippet, but guess the actual answer is no.  Temp variable it is then!